# Google Assistant's Privacy Policy

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es, privacy-policy

I don't intend to collect any user data from my Google Assistant app.

So I am in need of a minimal Privacy Policy, but I am unsure of the data collected by Google's Dialogflow, and how I am supposed to mention that in the Privacy Policy.

Comment: There is guidance on writing a Privacy Policy here: https://developers.google.com/actions/policies/privacy-policy-guide

Comment: @SachitMishra Thanks, I have been through there, but it wasn't showing a format.

Later I found sites which generate Privacy Policy. Converted it to the specs mentioned in the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not a lawyer, and asking legal questions on StackOverflow is not terribly wise in general.

However - the Google reviewers are primarily concerned with what **you** are specifically doing and collecting. Users have already agreed to Google accessing their information.

You can reference Google's [API Terms of Service](https://developers.google.com/terms/#section_7_privacy_and_copyright_protection) (which you agreed to when you used Dialogflow) which describes how they will use user information.

Comment: I would keep your suggestion in mind. I just assumed, as a fellow developer, someone might have created a simple Privacy Policy, just for a hello world app, which doesn't collect any data.